What is the math to get the correct CPU utilization with JVM OTEL Metrics
Currently Building a dashboard for the Java OTEL exporter
The metrics are:

jvm_cpu_time_seconds_total (jvm.cpu.time)
jvm_cpu_count (jvm.cpu.count)
jvm_cpu_recent_utilization_ratio (jvm.cpu.recent_utilization)

Having some trouble with the math.
Current state
According some other SO questions (1, 2, 3, 4) it should be just as simple as:
rate(jvm_cpu_time_seconds_total{}[$__rate_interval])

But here you can see both the ratio and the rate(seconds) ploted together

To my mind they should both be the same, but they are offset by 2 (the exact number of cores from the jvm_cpu_count)
One of these is missing a piece
Either
rate(jvm_cpu_time_seconds_total{}[$__rate_interval]) / jvm_cpu_count{}
OR
jvm_cpu_recent_utilization_ratio{} * jvm_cpu_count{}
And I don't know which one.
Reference
For referance this is what it looks like with the offset of the core count applied

(Basically identical, give or take variance)
Java Docs
As per com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean#getProcessCpuLoad():

Returns the "recent cpu usage" for the operating environment. This value is a double in the [0.0,1.0] interval. A value of 0.0 means that all CPUs were idle during the recent period of time observed, while a value of 1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running 100% of the time during the recent period being observed. All values betweens 0.0 and 1.0 are possible depending of the activities going on. If the recent cpu usage is not available, the method returns a negative value.

I am inclined to believe that ratio is correct.

"value of 1.0 means that all CPUs were actively running 100%"

But does that mean the conventional wisdom of the rate(Seconds) is wrong? did we always need to do: rate(Seconds) * core_count ?
Or is this a special case?

Questions you linked are not about JVM metrics. Meaning of the metric really depends on the exporter. For example, node_cpu_seconds_total from third question has label cpu, and you need to account for possible multiple cpus/cores in your query there.

And if you want to get CPU utilization in percents you should use either jvm_cpu_recent_utilization_ratio. But I expect it to be close match to the rate(...)/jvm_cpu_count, disregarding minor discrepancies regarding rate interpolation.

@markalex If you want to you can answer the question, so far yours is the best explanation.
